# Unit Testing ref structs with private fields via Reflection

Tags: c#

I implemented a pair of ref structs and wanted to write some unit tests for them. Naturally, all the fields are private. How do I test that the fields have correct values after certain operations assuming that the API is not supposed to reveal the internal workings of the class? I'd like to avoid modifying the ref structs themselves just to accomodate the tests.

My first go-to was reflection, to access the private fields, but the issue with this approach is that there's no way I can make it access the ref struct because i'd either have to box it in an object at some point, or use it as a generic type argument (which is also illegal for ref structs).

Is there maybe some code-gen library or something that can do this, or am I missing some other approach/solution?

Comment: I know I'm leaving myself open for a "frame challenge" here, but an answer of "don't do that" wont help me much. This class needs lots of testing, and it needs to be completely rock solid. I need to know for a fact that its internal values are correct.

Comment: Can you show any class to test so it's possible to work something out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ref structs cannot be used as generic type parameters, but this can be worked around with predefined delegate types.

This is probably ill-advised, but it does seem to work:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public static TDelegate CreateAccessor<TDelegate>(string memberName) where TDelegate : Delegate
{
    var invokeMethod = typeof(TDelegate).GetMethod("Invoke");
    if (invokeMethod == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"{typeof(TDelegate)} signature could not be determined.");

    var delegateParameters = invokeMethod.GetParameters();    
    if (delegateParameters.Length != 1)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Delegate must have a single parameter.");

    var paramType = delegateParameters[0].ParameterType;

    var objParam = Expression.Parameter(paramType, "obj");
    var memberExpr = Expression.PropertyOrField(objParam, memberName);
    Expression returnExpr = memberExpr;
    if (invokeMethod.ReturnType != memberExpr.Type)
        returnExpr = Expression.ConvertChecked(memberExpr, invokeMethod.ReturnType);

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<TDelegate>(returnExpr, $"Access{paramType.Name}_{memberName}", new [] { objParam });
    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

Usage:

```
ref struct Foo
{
    private string A;
    private int B;

    public Foo(string a, int b)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }
}

delegate object FooAccessor(Foo foo);
// or
delegate T FooAccessor<T>(Foo foo);

var foo = new Foo("abc", 123);
var a = CreateAccessor<FooAccessor<string>>("A")(foo);
var b = CreateAccessor<FooAccessor<int>>("B")(foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here is code for setter as well:

```
public static TDelegate CreateSetter<TDelegate>(string memberName) where TDelegate : Delegate
{
    var invokeMethod = typeof(TDelegate).GetMethod("Invoke");
    if (invokeMethod == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"{typeof(TDelegate)} signature could not be determined.");

    var delegateParameters = invokeMethod.GetParameters();
    if (delegateParameters.Length != 2)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Delegate must have a 2 parameters.");

    var objParamType = delegateParameters[0].ParameterType;
    var toSetParamType = delegateParameters[1].ParameterType;

    var objParam = Expression.Parameter(objParamType, "obj");
    var memberExpr = Expression.PropertyOrField(objParam, memberName);

    var toSetParam = Expression.Parameter(toSetParamType, "toSet");

    var assignExpre = Expression.Assign(memberExpr, toSetParam);
        
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<TDelegate>(assignExpre, $"Assign{objParamType.Name}_{memberName}", new[] { objParam, toSetParam });
    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

Use like:

```
    delegate T Utf8JsonReaderRefGetter<T>(ref Utf8JsonReader foo);
    delegate T Utf8JsonReaderGetter<T>(Utf8JsonReader foo);
    delegate void Utf8JsonReaderSetter<T>(Utf8JsonReader foo, T value);
    delegate void Utf8JsonReaderRefSetter<T>(ref Utf8JsonReader foo, T value);

    var r = new Utf8JsonReader();

    var sConsumed1 = CreateSetter<Utf8JsonReaderSetter<int>>("_consumed");
    sConsumed1(r, 42); // does not work!

    var sConsumed2 = CreateSetter<Utf8JsonReaderRefSetter<int>>("_consumed");
    sConsumed2(ref r, 42); // set only works if ref

    var gConsumed1 = CreateAccessor<Utf8JsonReaderRefGetter<int>>("_consumed");
    var r1 = gConsumed1(ref r); // 42

    var gConsumed2 = CreateAccessor<Utf8JsonReaderGetter<int>>("_consumed");
    var r2 = gConsumed2(r); // 42, get works without ref too
```