# How do I pass a ref struct argument to a MethodInfo if the struct has a ReadOnlySpan field

Tags: c#, struct, reflection

I have a `MethodInfo` object that represents a method, and that method takes a `ref struct` as an argument, and that struct has a `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` field. How do I invoke the method via the `MethodInfo` object? I can't use `MethodInfo.Invoke` because `Invoke` requires the parameters as an `object?[]?` array and a `struct` with a `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` field can't be cast to an `object`.

So how can I invoke a method via reflection and pass it a ref struct value where that struct has a field of type `ReadOnlySpan`?

Comment: Structs _can_ be casted to `object`. It's just that there will be boxing. Do you not like boxing?

Comment: Sorry. Edited to include the ReadOnlySpan field

Comment: I am guessing it is an ReadOnly Ref Struct which can only live on the stack.

Comment: @TheGeneral Doh! Yes, it is a ref struct! How did I not notice that...  I'll edit the question. Easy answer now for somebody.

Comment: Possibly this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55878525/unit-testing-ref-structs-with-private-fields-via-reflection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved very simply with [`MethodInfo.CreateDelegate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.createdelegate?view=net-5.0).

Here is an example which uses [one of the generic overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.createdelegate?view=net-5.0#System_Reflection_MethodInfo_CreateDelegate__1_System_Object_), available as of .NET 5.0:

```
public ref struct MyRefStruct
{
    private ReadOnlySpan<byte> myReadOnlySpan;

    public MyRefStruct(ReadOnlySpan<byte> myReadOnlySpan) =>
        this.myReadOnlySpan = myReadOnlySpan;

    public void Print()
    {
        foreach (byte b in myReadOnlySpan)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(b);
        }
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    private void PrintMyRefStruct(MyRefStruct myRefStruct) => myRefStruct.Print();
}

delegate void MyDelegate(MyRefStruct myRefStruct);

var myClass = new MyClass();
var myRefStruct = new MyRefStruct(new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(new byte[] { 0, 1 }));

var methodInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod(
    "PrintMyRefStruct",
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic
);

methodInfo.CreateDelegate<MyDelegate>(myClass)(myRefStruct);
```

Comment: Much easier than the accepted answer, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since your `struct` would naturally be a `ref struct` which will live on the *stack* (and can't escape to the managed heap), you face several *compiler* limitations and have a few hurdles to overcome.

> - A ref struct can't be the element type of an array.
> - A ref struct can't be a declared type of a field of a class or a non-ref struct.
> - A ref struct can't implement interfaces.
> - A ref struct can't be boxed to System.ValueType or System.Object.
> - A ref struct can't be a type argument. vA ref struct variable can't be captured by a lambda expression or a local function.
> - A ref struct variable can't be used in an async method. However, you can use ref struct variables in synchronous methods, for example, in
>   those that return Task or Task.
> - A ref struct variable can't be used in iterators.

As you can see, `ref struct` can't be *boxed* on the `heap`. This means you will not be able to *cast* to an `object` and use `Invoke`. However you can use an *expression tree* or `relection.emit`

When using an *expression tree* you will need to use a *delegate* with `Expression.Lambda` as `ref struct` can't be used as *type parameters* in a `Func`.

**Given**

```
public readonly ref struct Bob
{
   public Bob(ReadOnlySpan<byte> myProperty)
      => MyProperty = myProperty;    

   public ReadOnlySpan<byte> MyProperty { get; }
}

...

public static byte DoSomething(Bob bob)
   => bob.MyProperty[1]; // return something from the span ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

delegate byte myDelegate(Bob asd);

...

var bytes = new byte[] {1, 2, 3};
var span = bytes.AsSpan();
var bob = new Bob(span);
```

**Usage**

```
var method = typeof(SomeType).GetMethod("DoSomething");
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Bob), "b");
var call = Expression.Call(method, parameter);
var expression = Expression.Lambda<myDelegate>(call, parameter);
var func = expression.Compile();
var result = func(bob);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Results**

```
2
```

---

Or with the [in parameter modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-parameter-modifier) you'll need to make use of [`MakeByRefType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.makebyreftype?view=netcore-3.1)

> Returns a Type object that represents the current type when passed as
> a ref parameter

```
public static byte DoSomething(in Bob bob)
  => bob.MyProperty[1]; // return something from the span ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

delegate byte myDelegate(in Bob asd);

...

var method = typeof(SomeType).GetMethod("DoSomething", new[] {typeof(Bob).MakeByRefType()});
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Bob).MakeByRefType(), "b");
var call = Expression.Call(method, parameter);
var expression = Expression.Lambda<myDelegate>(call, parameter);
var func = expression.Compile();
var result = func(bob);
```

<sub>***Note** : This code is not the bastion perfect expression'ing, however it should work. Also this is built for a `static` method, you will need to pass in an instance if it's not*</sub>

Comment: This is a very good answer. Thank you. For non-static methods, something like `var instance = Expression.Constant(...)` and changing the call to `Expression.Call(instance, method, parameter)` works.