# How to invoke internal method with ref struct parameter and unknown return type

Tags: c#, struct, runtime, invoke, ref

I need to invoke `Read(ref Utf8JsonReader, Type, JsonSerializerOptions)` method from `System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<T>` which `T` is not known.

### Attempt 1

```cs
object converter = //Somehow get it;

Utf8JsonReader reader = //Somehow get it;
Type type = //Somehow get it;
JsonSerializerOptions options = //Somehow get them;

var result = converter.GetType()
                      .GetMethod("Read", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                      .Invoke(converter, new object[] { reader, type, options });
//                                                      ͠ ͠ ͠ ^͠ ͠ ͠ 
//                                      CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type
//                                  'System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader' to 'object'
```

Due to ref structs can't be boxed we can't do this.

### [Attempt 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67562655)

```cs
delegate object ReadDelegate(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options);

object converter = //Somehow get it;

Utf8JsonReader reader = //Somehow get it;
Type type = //Somehow get it;
JsonSerializerOptions options = //Somehow get them;

var result = converter.GetType()
                      .GetMethod("Read", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                      .CreateDelegate<ReadDelegate>(converter)(ref reader, type, options);
```

It works if `Read(ref Utf8JsonReader, Type, JsonSerializerOptions)` returns reference types (I have tested `int[]`, `string`), but value types (I have tested `int`, `struct`) produce `System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot bind to the target method because its signature is not compatible with that of the delegate type.'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
delegate object ReadDelegate(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options);

object converter = //Somehow get it;

Utf8JsonReader reader = //Somehow get it;
Type type = //Somehow get it;
JsonSerializerOptions options = //Somehow get them;

var instance = Expression.Constant(converter);
var method = converter.GetType().GetMethod("Read", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
var parameters = method.GetParameters().Select(p => Expression.Parameter(p.ParameterType, p.Name)).ToArray();

var call = Expression.Call(instance, method, parameters);
var cast = Expression.TypeAs(call, typeof(object));

var @delegate = Expression.Lambda<ReadDelegate>(cast, parameters);
    
var result = @delegate.Compile()(ref reader, type, options);
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to add explaination of your code ?

Comment: Cool answer, could you explain how it works?